# How to fix php error for Click counter feature

Tags: php

I am using the following script:
http://fofwebdesign.co.uk/template/_testing/click-count/

And I keep receiving the following error:
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in .../public_html/counter.php on line 18

```
<?php 
$file = 'counter.txt'; // path to text file that stores counts
$fh = fopen($file, 'r+');
$id = $_REQUEST['id']; // posted from page
$lines = '';
while(!feof($fh)){
    $line = explode('||', fgets($fh));
    $item = trim($line[0]);
    $num = trim($line[1]);
    if(!empty($item)){
        if($item == $id){
            $num++; // increment count by 1
            echo $num;
            }
        $lines .= "$item||$num\r\n";
        }
    } 
file_put_contents($file, $lines);
fclose($fh);

?>
```

I am not sure what is causing it as I made no modifications to the script. Is it related to my hosting?

Help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: That means there is no `$line[1]` element, possibly because your `explode()` string doesn't contain more than one element. What is in `$fh` at the point you get the error message?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i have checked other answers but none of them are relevant.

Comment: @droopsnoot On my index file there is:
<?php 

$clickcount = explode("\n", file_get_contents('counter.txt'));
foreach($clickcount as $line){
 $tmp = explode('||', $line);
 $count[trim($tmp[0])] = trim($tmp[1]);
 }

?>

Comment: @droopsnoot and <script>
var clicks = document.querySelectorAll('.click-trigger'); // IE8
for(var i = 0; i < clicks.length; i++){
 clicks[i].onclick = function(){
  var id = this.getAttribute('data-click-id');
  var post = 'id='+id; // post string
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('POST', 'counter.php', true);
  req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  req.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if (req.readyState != 4 || req.status != 200) return; 
   document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = req.responseText;
 };req.send(post);}}</script>

Comment: @droopsnoot but on every button there is:
<button class="click-trigger" data-click-id="click-001">Click Me</button> 
Clicked <span id="click-001" class="click-count"><?php echo $count['click-001'];?></span> times.

Comment: Don't put multiple lines of code in comments - you can't format them. If they are relevant, edit your question and put them in there where you can make them readable.

Comment: None of that seems to go anywhere near the error that you were asking about. As I asked earlier, what is in `$fh` when your code runs?